# string subtracted by string is not good by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, subtraction

Hey so im making a code and trying to subtract damaga from opponents hp and print it. But it always says:

```
     print("your max damage is " + damage + " damage, opponent has " + str(opponentHp) - str(random.randint(10, damage)))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

and as you can see i tried to convert it to string but it doesnt help

```
damage = 15
hp = 90

    opponentHp = random.randint(70, 110)
    print("your opponent has " + str(opponentHp) + " hp")
    attackDefense = input("attack:")
    elif  attackDefense == "attack":
        print("your max damage is " + damage + " damage, opponent has " + (str(opponentHp) - str(random.randint(10, damage))))
```

Comment: First, you cannot "add" (concatenate) a string and a  number. Second, strings cannot be subtracted. You should read about data types in Python.

Comment: You can only add strings to strings, and you can only subtract numbers from numbers.  You can convert between the two, but make sure you're doing it at the right time and in the right place for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `damage` is still of type `int`. Formatting output like this will go a lot smoother with f-strings:

```py
opponentHp -= random.randint(10, damage)
print(f"your max damage is {damage} damage, opponent has {opponentHp}")
```

Comment: i could have noticed. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues here. First, since `damage` is an `int`, when you try to concatenate it to a string via the `+` operator, that doesn't work, hence the error. You have to convert it to a string in order to put it into a display string (e.g. `"..." + str(damage) + "..."`).

The second issue is that you're trying to subtract strings from each other for some reason. That's an undefined operation in Python and will also result in an error. It doesn't make sense to try and subtract a string from a string. You can only subtract numbers from numbers. You have to convert them to a string only after the subtraction.

So, your fixed code would be:

```
print("your max damage is " + str(damage) + " damage, opponent has " + str(opponentHp - random.randint(10, damage)))
```

Or, a simpler way to do things is to use an f-string, which doesn't require conversion to `str()`:

```
print(f"your max damage is {damage} damage, opponent has {opponentHp - random.randint(10, damage)}")
```

Comment: i could have noticed. Thanks